# Dates are overlapped in Highchart's areachart

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am using Highcharts area graph. 
The type of the chart is "datetime".

The X-Axis labels get well adjusted as long as

- Either the width of the chart container div is less than 900px
- Or the width is not specified for the div

When I set the width of the container of the div more than 900px, either the labels are appended with the dots or get overlapped.

How it can be resolved. Thanks in advance for any suggestion or help.

Comment: for reference please check the link : https://jsfiddle.net/MeChinmayee/3df93jud/1/

Comment: how about setting an array that combines date and data : http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/whhcohbb/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `tickInterval` option to the x-Axis. This option determines the distance between the individual ticks. For example setting it to

```
tickInterval: 24*3600*1000
```

which resembles on day in milliseconds yields no overlapping labels for your chart:

https://jsfiddle.net/doc_snyder/mwzd1rc8/1/

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. The tickInterval property works well, but it still leaves the tickmark on the X-Axis. However I found http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.units to be helpful. Thank you Highchart support team.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a new option provided below by highcharts if you are comfortable with showing the labels in 2 or more lines and if you do not want rotated labels.

```
staggerLines: 2
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bhavinpatel/153eh40z/